# Jquery loading wrong html via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my website I have a file called `learn-more.html` , it's used to load stuff from index.html using AJAX.

**learn-more.html**

```
<div id="something" class="hero-unit span-one-third" style="position: relative;">
    Foo Bar
</div>

<div id="main-images" class="hero-unit span-one-third" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="learn-more-photo" class="span-one-third">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

**I have the following script located in index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#learn-more-button").click(function() {
                $.get('ajax/learn-more.html #main-images', function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                });
</script>
```

**Problem:**
The alert prints the contents of: `learn-more.html`

```
<div id="something" class="hero-unit span-one-third" style="position: relative;">
Foo Bar
</div>

<div id="main-images" class="hero-unit span-one-third" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="learn-more-photo" class="span-one-third">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Expected**
The alert should print the content of: `<div id="main-images">`

```
<div id="learn-more-photo" class="span-one-third">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
</div>
```

What could be going on here ?

EDIT: I'm willing to upload a .zip with the real files... it's just index.html plust learn-more.html and the css, if anyone is interested let me know.

EDIT2: This prints out the whole learn-more.html content

```
$.get('ajax/learn-more.html #main-images', function (data) {            
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `var foo = $(data).html()`?  You're putting the results of the ajax call into a DOM fragment and then extracting the HTML from that.  Why not just `alert(data)`?

Comment: Try `$.load` instead of `$.get`

Comment: Updated the example, sorry for that :)

Comment: @dyelawn Nothing happens if I use $.load (I don't even get an alert by just replacing $.get with $.load

Comment: `$.load()` is a little bit different than `$.get();`, so you can't just switch the words in your code. With `$.get();` you'd need to be using server-side scripting on the page you're calling (php or asp or etc. instead of html). With `$.load()` you can get specific elements using the hashtag identifier for the `id` attribute as you've written it in your code.

Comment: @dyelawn I know that, I tried what 'Jon' suggested without getting an alert...

Comment: there is an extra space in "ajax/learn-more.html #main-images" after html.. try removing that

Comment: Is alerting with the image your end-goal? Or do you want to put the image somewhere on the page making the call? `$.load` is not a global function, so you can't call it on nothing. But I assume you want to do something with the image other than just making it appear in an alert? If so, call `$.load` on the place you want the image to go. If your end goal is to do nothing more than display an alert, Adam's response below should point you in the right direction.

Comment: In reality I want to prepend a div with an image to the content of the #main-images div html.

Comment: I'm confused. is the #main-images div on your page that the ajax call is made from, or is it on the page that your ajax call is directed towards? If I had a div with #my-div, and I wanted to get the image from your html page, then prepend it to #my-div, I'd do: `<div id="my-div"><div id="load-target"></div></div><script>$('#load-target').load('ajax/learnmore.html #main-images');</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue,

$(data) returns an array of elements and not a jQuery object. $(data)[x] contains the element I was looking for.

To retrieve  it, I ended up using

```
$(data).filter('#main-images');
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$.get('ajax/learn-more.html', function (data) {
    var foo = $("#main-images", data);

    alert(foo.html());
});
```

**EDIT**

Hmm, try these alerts to see if we're close:

```
$.get('ajax/learn-more.html', function (data) {
    var foo = $("#main-images", data);

    alert(foo.length);
    alert(foo.hasClass('hero-unit span-one-third')); 
    alert(foo.html());
});
```

**EDIT**

Maybe try wrapping the data variable in the jQuery function?

```
$.get('ajax/learn-more.html', function (data) {
    data = $(data);

    var foo = $("#main-images", data);

    alert(foo.length);
    alert(foo.hasClass('hero-unit span-one-third')); 
    alert(foo.html());
});
```

Comment: If I do alert(foo) I get [object Object] , if I do : var foo = $("#main-images", data).html(); and then alert(foo) I get 'null'. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Mr.Gando - not sure - check my edit - maybe that'll help debug this

Comment: Got this: 

alert(foo.length); => 0
alert(foo.hasClass('hero-unit span-one-third')); => false
alert(foo.html()); => null

Comment: @Mr.Gando - looks like the html coming back isn't what you expected.  Add an alert(data); to see exactly what's coming over.  You might also  inspect firebug / chrome dev tools to see the network calls going across.

Comment: Checkout the EDIT2 in my question, that returned the whole html content of learn-more.html ... maybe could lead to an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Gando - I really don't know.  The code should work.  Maybe instead of `$("#main-images", data);` try `$(".hero-unit span-one-third", data);`

Comment: @Mr.Gando Regardless of if you are using the `load` or `get` method for your ajax, the data passed to the callback will be the entire html content.  So your alert(data) will always be the whole page.  The idea here is that you retrieve the whole page via ajax, and then select the parts that you want to use after it's retrieved.  If you look at the example in my answer, alert(data) will give you the whole page, but only the content in `#main-images` would get loaded into the target element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$.get()` to do this, try the `load` method instead:

```
$(target).load('ajax/learn-more.html #main-images', function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Just edited this example to include a target object that you would be loading this content into.  So, your target would be an element in your `index.html` file, and when the load method runs successfully, the contents of the target would be replaced with the contents of the `#main-images` element in `learn-more.html`.  If it returns nothing, make sure your path to `learn-more.html` is correct.  Would also suggest using console.log(data) instead of alert(data) for unobtrusive debugging in both Web Inspector (WebKit browsers) and Firebug (Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

try mentioning response `datatype`

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#learn-more-button").click(function() {
                $.get('ajax/learn-more.html', function (data) {
                        alert($(data).find('div#main-images').html());
                },
               'html');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: i have updated the answer and added response datatype.. try it out now.

Comment: still returns null... I edited my question with a small update.

Comment: did you try removing extra space in link after .html

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#learn-more-button").click(function() {
                $.get('ajax/learn-more.html', function (data) {
                        var main_images = $(data).find("#main-images");
                        alert(main_images);
                });
</script>
```